# How to get safe area insets from within a SKScene subclass

Tags: ios, swift, layout, sprite-kit, safearea

I'm subclassing `SKScene` to create a main menu scene and would like to add a button at the top left of the screen. Since the status bar is enabled I would want buttons to be placed below the status bar. To do this, I need the safe area insets, but every time I try to access the safe area insets I get the value of 0.0 for each edge.

According to the documentation, this happens when the view hasn't appeared on screen, however, I can't figure out a way to access the safe area insets after the view has appeared. `sceneDidLoad()`, `didMove(to:)`, etc. all seem to be called before `viewDidAppear()` so I'm not able to acquire the safe area insets from within those functions.

Can anyone tell me how I can place my SKSpriteNodes (menu buttons) within the safe area by using `safeAreaInsets`? Keep in mind I need to access it within the SKScene subclass so I can place my menu button properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

formerly it was easy to access insets from within `SKScene`

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets
```

'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0. however you can still access insets like this

```
self.view?.window?.windowScene?.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets
```

but, as you say, this doesn't work within the launch cycle of SKScene. you have to access it *afterward*.

as a solution i recommend the following pattern: centralize all your SKNode positioning into a function
called `rebuild`. at the start of that rebuild function also update safeAreaInsets. then call rebuild from `UIViewController.viewDidAppear`

SKScene:

```
var topInset:CGFloat = 0

func pollInsets() {
     topInset = self.view?.window?.windowScene?.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0
     print("topInset: \(topInset)")
}

func rebuild() {
     pollInsets()
     
     //reposition your buttons, etc.
}
```

UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
          (view.scene as? GameScene)?.rebuild()
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I was giving this more thought and realised it's probably *not good practise* to have my SKScene position nodes just below the status bar. The reason for this is an SKScene isn't guaranteed to have the dimensions of the full screen. In fact, you must provide an SKScene with its dimension so it could also be 100x100. Do you think this reasoning is correct and I shouldn't try doing this from within SKScene? If you agree that I shouldn't do it here what would you recommend I do? Perhaps make a new VC or have a custom initialiser / function within the SKScene subclass? Thanks for your time.

Comment: a full screen SKScene is very common. but it depends on your needs of course. if you go full screen you'll need to accommodate more variability: you will likely have users with different screen sizes and potentially device rotation, all of which might affect how nodes need to be positioned. (the `rebuild` function helps here.) alternately you can go with a fixed scene size. then you sort of have the same problem, only now the scene is floating inside a larger autolayout, either SwiftUI or UIKit.